# Discord.py trying to have a bot ask a series of questions and assign variables to answers?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to ask people a series of questions if they enter a certain command. I want the bot to ask the question, then assign a variable to their response. For example:

**Bot:** 'What's your name?'
**User:** *Bananas*
**Bot:** 'What's your question?'
**User:** *How to get bananas*

I.e., the bot would wait for the answer then send the next question. In the end, I'd want to create variables like `Name` and `Question` which are identical to the messages sent. Is this possible? How can I do this?

My first code attempt (the printing is just a placeholder command to test and see if the variables work). It doesn't work at all:

```py
client.PreferredName=False
    client.Question=False

    await message.channel.send('Please enter your preferred name below:')
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if not message.author == client.user:
       client.PreferredName=message.content
       await message.channel.send('Please enter your question:')

      @client.event
      async def on_message(message):
        if not message.author == client.user:

          client.Question=message.content

    print(str(client.PreferredName) + str(client.Question))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) to wait for user input. I created the function `message` that sends your question and waits for a response, then returns it and stores it in variables (e.g. `name` and `question`). Instead of using the `on_message` event, I created the command `test`, that you can use with your prefix (e.g. `!test`).

```py
async def message(ctx, message : str, timeout: float): # this function is used to send question and wait for response
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
        
    await ctx.send(message)
    response = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=timeout)

    return response.content # return's user's response

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):   
    try:
        name = await message(ctx, "What's your name?", timeout=60.0) # you can change timeout (how long bot will wait for response - in seconds)
        question = await message(ctx, "What's your question?", timeout=60.0) # this line is used to ask questions. You can add more if you want

    except asyncio.TimeoutError: # checks if the time limit for a response was exceeded
        await ctx.send("You were too slow to answer!")
    else: # if it wasn't
        await ctx.send(f'Your name is "{name}" and your question: "{question}"') # you can do something with content here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `wait_for` function:

```py
import asyncio


questions = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]  # specify your questions here


@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx):
    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        await ctx.send(question)
        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
    if len(questions) != len(answers):
        pass  # member hasn't completed the poll
    else:
        pass  # member has completed the poll. You can get answers using answers list
```

This solution is scalable because you can ask a lot of questions. Just edit `questions` variable. You don't need to write new code for it.